# Express Entry : Applying with dependents

Tags: canada, residency, express-entry

I am planning to apply for Canadian PR via Express Entry under FSW.
I am married and have a kid. Please can you suggest :

1. Is it mandatory to include dependents (spouse and son) while applying?
2. If it is not mandatory, shall I apply with them or shall I apply for them afterwards when I am settled in Canada with a job? What is the better approach?

Comment: "Better" is highly subjective and would depend on what you're trying to achieve. This is purely anecdotal, so not an answer, but Canada seems to prefer family applications rather to family reunification ones. I assume you want your kid to move with you ?